# GitLab Vagrant VM takes forever to provision, due to Berkshelf backup?

Tags: vagrant, provisioning, gitlab, berkshelf

I have a GitLab VM with Vagrant based on the [GitLab Cookbook](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cookbook-gitlab) in production mode. I was running fine, until I had to restart the host today.

This is my output when I am running `vagrant provision`:

```
$ vagrant provision
[Berkshelf] This version of the Berkshelf plugin has not been fully tested on this version of Vagrant.
[Berkshelf] You should check for a newer version of vagrant-berkshelf.
[Berkshelf] If you encounter any errors with this version, please report them at https://github.com/RiotGames/vagrant-berkshelf/issues
[Berkshelf] You can also join the discussion in #berkshelf on Freenode.
[Berkshelf] Updating Vagrant's berkshelf: '/Users/admin/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140116-30359-fggony-default'
[Berkshelf] Using gitlab (0.6.4)
[Berkshelf] Using yum (2.4.2)
[Berkshelf] Installing magic_shell (0.3.2) from git: 'git://github.com/customink-webops/magic_shell.git' with branch: 'master' at ref: '447b4b67420d3a7a749d2dd3b13a7f9aceb54c36'
[Berkshelf] Installing monit (1.4.0) from git: 'git://github.com/phlipper/chef-monit.git' with branch: 'master' at ref: '276c99ba08869ebd5117267d91a2ff6aa0d9fc6b'
[Berkshelf] Using redisio (1.7.0)
[Berkshelf] Using ulimit (0.3.2)
[Berkshelf] Using ruby_build (0.8.0)
[Berkshelf] Using postgresql (3.3.4)
[Berkshelf] Using apt (2.3.0)
[Berkshelf] Using build-essential (1.4.2)
[Berkshelf] Using openssl (1.1.0)
[Berkshelf] Using mysql (4.0.10)
[Berkshelf] Using database (1.5.2)
[Berkshelf] Using aws (1.0.0)
[Berkshelf] Using xfs (1.1.0)
[Berkshelf] Using postfix (3.0.4)
[Berkshelf] Using phantomjs (1.0.3)
[Berkshelf] Using chocolatey (0.0.5)
[Berkshelf] Using powershell (1.1.2)
[Berkshelf] Using windows (1.11.0)
[Berkshelf] Using chef_handler (1.1.4)
```

Now it stays forever (more than 40 minutes) here ... after looking at some `lsof` output I found out that *Berkshelf* is creating a backup of **all** my files from `home_git`, which contains the application and repositories several GB in size.

```
ruby      10049 admin    7r     REG                1,2   59361467  99893126 /Users/admin/********/home_git/gitlab-satellites/*********/**********/.git/objects/89/61108fd29d60d311dd44b0e4d7ed0ddd7233ee
ruby      10049 admin    8w     REG                1,2   56639488 103952415 /Users/admin/.berkshelf/default/tmp/d20140206-10049-1q37zex/gitlab/home_git/gitlab-satellites/********/*********/.git/objects/89/61108fd29d60d311dd44b0e4d7ed0ddd7233ee
```

But these files don't have to be backed up, when I provision the VM.

Questions:

- It looks like *Berkshelf* is treating these files as part of one of my cookbooks?
- How could I tell *Berkshelf* to ignore this folder?

... or any other hint is very welcome! I also tried to disable *Berkshelf* without luck.

### Workaround

If I move away the `home_git` folder the provisioning process runs through fast and smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

Berkshelf 2 needed all of the cookbooks in a single location, since it compiled the metadata requirements on the fly. Berkshelf 3 uses a hosted API server, so this is no longer the case for *most* cookbooks.

However, it's also worth nothing that we are pushing people away from Vagrant Berkshelf and into Test Kitchen, as explained in this blog post: https://sethvargo.com/the-future-of-vagrant-berkshelf/